# Java: Method annotation to suppress NullPointerException warning

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception, annotations

I have the following helper method in my code that asserts some property about a member field in my class.

```
private @Nullable Controller mController;

private boolean isControllerReady() {
  return mController != null && mController.isReady();
}
```

Elsewhere in my code, I invoke something like this...

```
if (isControllerReady() && mController.canDoSomething()) {
  mController.doSomething();
}
```

My Android Studio gives me a warning on `canDoSomething()`:

```
Method invocation 'canDoSomething' may produce 'NullPointerException'
```

This should be a false positive. Is it possible to annotate `isControllerReady` so that the IDE suppresses/ignores this NPE warning on `canDoSomething`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [@SuppressWarnings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) annotation is what you're looking for. Then you'd annotate your method and pass in the compiler warning (or warnings) that you'd like to suppress.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"NullableProblems"})
private boolean isControllerReady() {
  return mController != null && mController.isReady();
}
```

Alternatively on Intellij (this should also work in Android Studio), you can press `Alt + Enter` on the highlighted warning and suppress it from there.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html?keymap=primary_xwin#suppress-inspections

Edit: formatting

Comment: I don't think that's the solution, at least the one you provided doesn't work. I'm pretty sure the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation is to suppress warnings _within_ the method that it annotates. I'm trying to suppress NPE warnings where that method is used in conjunction with other statements that should assert `mController` is not `null`. I could apply `@SuppressWarnings` to every place I try to use `mController` but that defeats the purpose of this question.

Comment: Ahh yes you're right, `@SuppressWarnings` scope is at the method (or class level) and `//noinspection` at the statement level.

Answer (score 1):

As you annotated mController as a Nullable, the compiler tries to warn you to check if mController is not null before you invoke any operation on the object.

You can simply add a null check in the condition.

```
if (isControllerReady() && mController != null && mController.canDoSomething()) {
  mController.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Of course I can do that, but that defeats the purpose. `isControllerReady()` already does a null check but the IDE doesn't recognize that during static analysis so I want to know if there's a way to explicitly tell the IDE the `isControllerReady()` helper method should act as the NPE assertion.

Comment: As mController is nullable, it will always give you a warning for NullPointer. If you are confident if mController never is null then you can remove @Nullable annotation from `private @Nullable Controller mController;`.

Comment: Well the whole point is that `mController` is indeed `@Nullable`. I basically want the IDE to treat my `isControllerReady()` similar to the `mController != null` check – ideally via some annotation.